# How to fill MDTextField Employee ID,after Scanning barcode success

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

Good Evening all Members,
Please help me,I want to ask about my syntax kivymd.
I want to MDTextField Employee autofill with code employee from QRCode after scanning barcode finish.

Here's my code:
Here Main.py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.button.button import MDRectangleFlatIconButton
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.camera import Camera
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from pyzbar.pyzbar import ZBarSymbol
from kivy_garden.zbarcam import ZBarCam
from kivymd.uix.snackbar import Snackbar
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen,FadeTransition,SwapTransition
from kivymd.uix.screenmanager import MDScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.transition.transition import MDFadeSlideTransition,MDTransitionBase
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivy.properties import (DictProperty,ListProperty,NumericProperty,ObjectProperty,OptionProperty,StringProperty,)
from kivy.core.window import Window 

Builder.load_file("main_screen.kv")
Builder.load_file("molding_screen.kv")
# Builder.load_file("kvs/page/punching_screen.kv")
# Builder.load_file("kvs/page/oy_screen.kv")

Window.size=(360,640)

class CameraPopup(MDBoxLayout):
    
    def build(self):
        """Initializes the Application and returns the root widget"""
    # pass
    

class WindowManager(MDScreenManager):
    """A window manager to manage switching between sceens."""


class MainScreen(MDScreen):
    """A screen that display the form scanning Molding Process."""
    
    def build(self):
        """Initializes the Application and returns the root widget"""
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
    
class MoldingScreen(MDScreen):
    """A screen that display the form scanning Molding Process."""
    judul="MOLDING PROCESS"
    
    def build(self):
        """Initializes the Application and returns the root widget"""
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        
    def show_camera_popup(self):
        isi = CameraPopup()
        self.dialog = MDDialog(
            title="QRCODE SCAN",
            auto_dismiss=False,
            text="Isi dari camera scan.",
            type="custom",
            content_cls=isi,
            buttons=[
                    MDRectangleFlatIconButton(
                        text="CLOSE CAMERA",
                        theme_text_color="Custom",
                        text_color="white",
                        size_hint_x=1,
                        theme_bg_color="Custom",
                        md_bg_color="blue",
                        # md_bg_color=0,0,0,1
                        font_size=22,
                        padding=10,
                        on_release=self.close_scanner
                    ),
                ],          
            
        )
        self.dialog.open() 
                        
        # self.ids.text_id_employee.text = self.isiqr
        # self.close_scanner()
        
    def close_scanner(self,obj):
        self.dialog.dismiss()
                      
    # pass
        
        
class MainApp(MDApp):
    
    def build(self):
        """Initializes the Application and returns the root widget"""
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        self.title = "SCANNING PROCESS"
        
        self.wm = WindowManager(transition=MDFadeSlideTransition())
        screens = [
            MainScreen(name="main"),
            MoldingScreen(name="molding"),

        ]
        for screen in screens:
            self.wm.add_widget(screen)

        return self.wm
    
    def change_screen(self, screen):
        """Change screen using the window manager."""
        self.wm.current = screen
         
    def on_symbols(self,instance,symbols):

        if not symbols == "":
            for symbol in symbols:
                self.lblqrcode = symbol.data.decode()
                print("QRCode is :",symbol.data.decode())
                Snackbar(
                    text="Your QR Is {}".format(symbol.data.decode()),
                    md_bg_color="green",
                    font_size=20
                ).open()
        # self.isiqr = self.lblqrcode       
        # self.ids.id_hasil.text = self.lblqrcode     
    
  
    def capture_image(self):
        pass
    
    def show_result(self):
        pass
        
                   

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

Here main_screen.kv

```
<MainScreen>:
    
    MDTopAppBar:
        title: "PROCESS MAIN MENU"
        # elevation: 4
        elevation_normal_color: (0, 0, 0, 0)  # Set elevation normal color to transparent
        elevation_pressed_color: (0, 0, 0, 0)  # Set elevation pressed color to transparent
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        theme_bg_color:"Custom"
        md_bg_color: 35/255, 122/255, 255/255, 0.89
        theme_text_color: "Custom"
        text_color: "white"
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x:x]]
        
        GridLayout:
            id: grid_layout
            cols: 3
            adaptive_height: True
            spacing: dp(8)
            padding: dp(0),dp(45),dp(0),dp(0)
        

            MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
                text: "MOLDING"
                size_hint_y:None
                height:dp(100)
                theme_bg_color: "Custom"
                md_bg_color: 35/255, 122/255, 255/255, 0.89
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: "white"
                font_size: dp(12)
                line_color:211/255, 215/255, 250/255, 0.8
                theme_icon_color: "Custom"
                size_hint_x:0.35
                padding: dp(12)
                on_press: app.change_screen('molding')
                
            MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
                text: "OVEN"
                size_hint_y:None
                height:dp(100)
                theme_bg_color: "Custom"
                md_bg_color: 35/255, 122/255, 255/255, 0.89
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: "white"
                font_size: dp(12)
                line_color: 211/255, 215/255, 250/255, 0.8
                theme_icon_color: "Custom"
                size_hint_x:0.35
                padding: dp(12)
                
            MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
                text: "PUNCHING"
                size_hint_y:None
                height:dp(100)
                theme_bg_color: "Custom"
                md_bg_color: 35/255, 122/255, 255/255, 0.89
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: "white"
                font_size: dp(12)
                line_color: 211/255, 215/255, 250/255, 0.8
                theme_icon_color: "Custom"
                size_hint_x:0.35
                padding: dp(12)
                
            MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
                text: "PREPUSH"
                size_hint_y:None
                height:dp(100)
                theme_bg_color: "Custom"
                md_bg_color: 35/255, 122/255, 255/255, 0.89
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: "white"
                font_size: dp(12)
                line_color:211/255, 215/255, 250/255, 0.8
                theme_icon_color: "Custom"
                size_hint_x:0.3
                padding: dp(12)
                
            MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
                text: "PATAGUN"
                size_hint_y:None
                height:dp(100)
                theme_bg_color: "Custom"
                md_bg_color: 35/255, 122/255, 255/255, 0.89
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: "white"
                font_size: dp(12)
                line_color: 211/255, 215/255, 250/255, 0.8
                theme_icon_color: "Custom"
                size_hint_x:0.3
                padding: dp(12)
                
            MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
                text: "CLEANING"
                size_hint_y:None
                height:dp(100)
                theme_bg_color: "Custom"
                md_bg_color: 35/255, 122/255, 255/255, 0.89
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: "white"
                font_size: dp(12)
                line_color: 211/255, 215/255, 250/255, 0.8
                theme_icon_color: "Custom"
                size_hint_x:0.3
                padding: dp(12)
                
            MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
                text: "OY"
                size_hint_y:None
                height:dp(100)
                theme_bg_color: "Custom"
                md_bg_color: 35/255, 122/255, 255/255, 0.89
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: "white"
                font_size: dp(12)
                line_color:211/255, 215/255, 250/255, 0.8
                theme_icon_color: "Custom"
                size_hint_x:0.3
                padding: dp(12)
                
            MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
                text: "FINISHING"
                size_hint_y:None
                height:dp(100)
                theme_bg_color: "Custom"
                md_bg_color: 35/255, 122/255, 255/255, 0.89
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: "white"
                font_size: dp(12)
                line_color: 211/255, 215/255, 250/255, 0.8
                theme_icon_color: "Custom"
                size_hint_x:0.3
                padding: dp(12)
                
            MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
                text: "MIP"
                size_hint_y:None
                height:dp(100)
                theme_bg_color: "Custom"
                md_bg_color: 35/255, 122/255, 255/255, 0.89
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: "white"
                font_size: dp(12)
                line_color: 211/255, 215/255, 250/255, 0.8
                theme_icon_color: "Custom"
                size_hint_x:0.3
                padding: dp(12)
                
            MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
                text: "RESISTANCE"
                size_hint_y:None
                height:dp(100)
                theme_bg_color: "Custom"
                md_bg_color: 35/255, 122/255, 255/255, 0.89
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: "white"
                font_size: dp(12)
                line_color:211/255, 215/255, 250/255, 0.8
                theme_icon_color: "Custom"
                size_hint_x:0.3
                padding: dp(12)
                
            MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
                text: "INSPECTION"
                size_hint_y:None
                height:dp(100)
                theme_bg_color: "Custom"
                md_bg_color: 35/255, 122/255, 255/255, 0.89
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: "white"
                font_size: dp(12)
                line_color: 211/255, 215/255, 250/255, 0.8
                theme_icon_color: "Custom"
                size_hint_x:0.3
                padding: dp(12)
                
            MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
                text: "GI INSPECTION"
                size_hint_y:None
                height:dp(100)
                theme_bg_color: "Custom"
                md_bg_color: 35/255, 122/255, 255/255, 0.89
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: "white"
                font_size: dp(12)
                line_color: 211/255, 215/255, 250/255, 0.8
                theme_icon_color: "Custom"
                size_hint_x:0.3
                padding: dp(12)
                
            MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
                text: "PACKING"
                size_hint_y:None
                height:dp(100)
                theme_bg_color: "Custom"
                md_bg_color: 35/255, 122/255, 255/255, 0.89
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: "white"
                font_size: dp(12)
                line_color: 211/255, 215/255, 250/255, 0.8
                theme_icon_color: "Custom"
                size_hint_x:0.3
                padding: dp(12)
                
            MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
                text: "STORE IN"
                size_hint_y:None
                height:dp(100)
                theme_bg_color: "Custom"
                md_bg_color: 35/255, 122/255, 255/255, 0.89
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: "white"
                font_size: dp(12)
                line_color: 211/255, 215/255, 250/255, 0.8
                theme_icon_color: "Custom"
                size_hint_x:0.3
                padding: dp(12)
                
            MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
                text: "STORE OUT"
                size_hint_y:None
                height:dp(100)
                theme_bg_color: "Custom"
                md_bg_color: 35/255, 122/255, 255/255, 0.89
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: "white"
                font_size: dp(12)
                line_color: 211/255, 215/255, 250/255, 0.8
                theme_icon_color: "Custom"
                size_hint_x:0.3
                padding: dp(12)
    
    
    MDBottomAppBar:
        elevation_normal_color: (0, 0, 0, 0)  # Set elevation normal color to transparent
        elevation_pressed_color: (0, 0, 0, 0)  # Set elevation pressed color to transparent
        theme_bg_color:"Custom"
        md_bg_color: 35/255, 122/255, 255/255, 0.89

        MDTopAppBar:
            icon: "home"
            font_size: dp(10)
            icon_color:35/255, 122/255, 255/255, 0.89
            type: "bottom"
            left_action_items: [["clipboard-search-outline", lambda x: x]]
            right_action_items: [["account", lambda x:x]] 
            elevation_normal_color: (0, 0, 0, 0)  # Set elevation normal color to transparent
            elevation_pressed_color: (0, 0, 0, 0)  # Set elevation pressed color to transparent
```

Here Molding_screen.kv

```
#:import ZBarCam kivy_garden.zbarcam.ZBarCam
#:import ZBarSymbol pyzbar.pyzbar.ZBarSymbol
<CameraPopup@MDBoxLayout>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    size_hint_y:None
    height:dp(500)
    line_color:35/255, 122/255, 255/255, 0.89
    line_width:1

    ZBarCam:
    id:zbarcam
        size_hint_y:1
        pos_hint_y:1
        # line_color:0,1,0,1
        # line_width:5
        code_types:ZBarSymbol.QRCODE.value,ZBarSymbol.EAN13.value,ZBarSymbol.CODE128.value,ZBarSymbol.CODE39.value,ZBarSymbol.CODE93.value,ZBarSymbol.EAN8.value,ZBarSymbol.EAN5.value,ZBarSymbol.EAN2.value,ZBarSymbol.EAN13.value,ZBarSymbol.I25.value,ZBarSymbol.UPCA.value,ZBarSymbol.UPCE.value,ZBarSymbol.CODABAR.value
        on_symbols:app.on_symbols(*args)


<MoldingScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDTopAppBar:
            title: root.judul
            elevation_normal_color: (0, 0, 0, 0)  # Set elevation normal color to transparent
            elevation_pressed_color: (0, 0, 0, 0)  # Set elevation pressed color to transparent
            # pos_hint: {"top": 1}
            theme_bg_color:"Custom"
            md_bg_color: 35/255, 122/255, 255/255, 0.89
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: "white"
         
            # spacing: dp(2)

        MDGridLayout:
            cols: 2
            padding: "10dp"
            spacing: "10dp"

            MDTextField:
                id: id_employee
                hint_text: "EMPLOYEE"
                helper_text: "Scan ID Employee"
                helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
                input_filter: "str"
                multiline: False

            MDIconButton:
                icon: "qrcode-scan"
                icon_size: "38sp"
                opacity: 0.5
                on_release:root.show_camera_popup()

            MDTextField:
                id: text_field
                hint_text: "MACHINE"
                helper_text: "Scan ID Employee"
                helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
                input_filter: "str"
                multiline: False

            MDIconButton:
                icon: "qrcode-scan"
                icon_size: "38sp"
                opacity: 0.5
                # on_release:app.show_camera_popup()

            MDTextField:
                id: text_field
                hint_text: "JOBNUMBER"
                helper_text: "Scan ID Employee"
                helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
                input_filter: "str"
                multiline: False

            MDIconButton:
                icon: "qrcode-scan"
                icon_size: "38sp"
                opacity: 0.5
                # on_release:app.show_camera_popup()

            MDTextField:
                id: text_field
                hint_text: "QTY"
                helper_text: "Add Quantity Product"
                helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
                input_filter: "str"
                multiline: False

            MDIconButton:
                icon: "calculator-variant"
                icon_size: "38sp"
                opacity: 0.5
                # on_release:app.show_camera_popup()

            MDBoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                adaptive_height: True
                spacing: dp(2)
                # padding: dp(0),dp(20),dp(0),dp(0)
        
                MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
                    text: "SUBMIT"
                    size_hint_y:None
                    theme_bg_color: "Custom"
                    md_bg_color: 35/255, 122/255, 255/255, 0.89
                    theme_text_color: "Custom"
                    text_color: "white"
                    font_size: dp(18)
                    line_color:211/255, 215/255, 250/255, 0.8
                    size_hint_x:0.5
                    padding: dp(15)
                    post_hint_x:0.5
                

    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        adaptive_height: True
        spacing: dp(2)
        padding: dp(0),dp(20),dp(0),dp(0)

        MDBottomAppBar:
            theme_bg_color:"Custom"
            md_bg_color: 35/255, 122/255, 255/255, 0.89
        
            MDTopAppBar:
                icon:"home"
                theme_icon_color: "Custom"
                icon_color: "white"
                font_size: dp(10)
                icon_color:35/255, 122/255, 255/255, 0.89
                type: "bottom"
                left_action_items: [["home", lambda x: app.change_screen('main')]]
                right_action_items: [["account", lambda x:x]]
```

I have tried to parsing variable symbol.data.decode() to MDTextField ID Employee but failure.
I have tried for 3 days but no result or solved.

I Hope all members can teach me or make solve this problem and i will learn from this case.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).